# Insert some element according to Average number

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

im working on my rating system section now i want to add some element to template according to Average number for example if user rating is 4 i should insert 4 start div element how can i do that ?

```
number = 4

<div *ngFor="let i of ?"><i class="mdi mdi-star"</i</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a method that builds an empty array with 'n' items/length, so the ngFor will iterate over it

template.html

```
<div *ngFor="let i of buildArray()"><i class="mdi mdi-star"></i></div>
```

component.ts

```
number = 4;
//more logic
buildArray() {
   return new Array(this.number)
}
```